# Is ImageMagick the fastest way to overlay images? How do I make faster or is there a faster tech I'm unaware of?

Tags: imagemagick, gd, image-manipulation, graphicsmagick

I'm in the process of building an image manipulation Nginx CDN/cache server to overlay millions of unique SVG designs files on apparel jpegs. Similar tutorial here:  http://sumitbirla.com/2011/11/how-to-build-a-scalable-caching-resizing-image-server/

I have written a test script here:

```
<?php

$cmd = "composite GOSHEN.svg blank-tshirt.jpg -geometry 600x700+456+335 JPG:-";

header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
passthru($cmd);
exit();

?>
```

Here is an example result:

My issue is that ImageMagick is so slow.  Besides more CPU/Memory, are there any tricks to make it faster?  Are there any alternative technologies that could be faster to overlay images?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I have done some speed tests in the past and GD and Imagick can be faster than Imagemagick. Imagemagick is an external program while Imagick and GD are built into php. I would try a test and compare all three and see what you get.

Comment: You could use HTML5 Canvas Composite and SVG options to do the overlay. See https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation. I cannot say I have used them, but it is one quick way to do it. Python/OpenCV may also be faster than either GM or IM.

Comment: You say you want to do millions of overlays. Do you mean to do them all, up-front, en masse as a big batch? Or that you will do each one on demand, when needed? They are two different problems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[php-vips](https://github.com/libvips/php-vips/) can be quite a bit quicker than imagick. I made a test program for you:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use Jcupitt\Vips;

for($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {
    $base = Vips\Image::newFromFile($argv[1], ["access" => "sequential"]);
    $overlay = Vips\Image::newFromFile($argv[2], ["access" => "sequential"]);

    // centre the overlay on the image, but lift it up a bit    
    $left = ($base->width - $overlay->width) * 0.5;
    $top = ($base->height - $overlay->height) * 0.45;

    $out = $base->composite2($overlay, "over", ["x" => $left, "y" => $top]);

    // write to stdout with a mime header
    $out->jpegsave_mime();
}
```

Using the test images from your server:

http://build9.hometownapparel.com/pics/

Then running on my desktop machine (Ubuntu 17.10, a fast i7 CPU) I see:

```
$ time ./overlay.php blank-tshirt.jpg GOSHEN.svg > /dev/null
real    0m2.488s
user    0m13.446s
sys 0m0.328s
```

So about 25ms per image. I see this result (taken from the first iteration, obviously):

[image: sample output]

I tried a looping version of your imagemagick example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

header("Content-type: image/jpeg");

for($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {
    $cmd = "composite GOSHEN.svg blank-tshirt.jpg -geometry 600x700+456+335 JPG:-";

    passthru($cmd);
}
```

Running it against IM-6.9.7-4 (the version packaged for Ubuntu) I see:

```
$ time ./magick.php > /dev/null
real    0m29.084s
user    0m42.289s
sys 0m4.716s
```

Or 290ms per image. So on this test, php-vips is more than 10x faster. It's a bit unfair: imagick would probably be a little quicker than just shelling out to composite.

There's another benchmark here:

https://github.com/jcupitt/php-vips-bench

On that one, php-vips is about 4x faster than imagick and needs 8x less memory.

Here's the whole thing packaged as a Dockerfile you should be able to run anywhere:

https://github.com/jcupitt/docker-builds/tree/master/php-vips-ubuntu-16.04

Comment: I can't express my gratitude enough.  These benchmark speeds allow me to build my solution.  It's been a very long journey of difficult research and me banging my head on a wall over and over.  Thank you.

Comment: Yes, 25ms is quick enough that you can do it as part of page generation.

Comment: FYI.  I got php-vips working on my server.  The installation was tough, but my initial real-world tests have libvips performing 9-10x faster than ImageMagick.    More people need to know about this awesome software.  Thank you again for all your help.

Comment: Oh, no problem, I'm glad it's working. The installation was tricky mostly because Ubuntu 16.04 packages a rather old version of libvips and that had to be updated. Installation should be a two-liner (I think) on 18.04, due in two weeks.

Comment: I added a dockerfile with everything packaged. It should make install simpler.